# Estimate for the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta

I want to show the following:
Let $\delta>0$ be fixed. Then for $\sigma\ge \delta, s\not=1$, 
$$\sum_{n\le x}n^{-s}=\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+\zeta(s)+O(\tau x^{-\sigma})$$
where $s=\sigma+it,~\tau=|t|+4$ and $f(x)=O(g(x))\Leftrightarrow|f(x)|\le Cg(x)$ for a constant $C$.

Now, I have already proved the identity 
$$\sum_{n\le x}=\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+\zeta(s)-\frac{\{x\}}{x^s}+s\int_x^\infty\{u\}u^{-s-1}du$$
and obviously $|\int_x^\infty\{u\}u^{-s-1}du|\le \frac{x^{-\sigma}}{\sigma}$. However, I don't know what to do with the prefactor $s$ and where $\tau$ comes from.

Comment: All you need to conclude is $\displaystyle\frac{s}{\sigma} = \mathcal{O}(\tau)$.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I know but I'm not sure why this holds. I have tried the following though: $\frac{|s|}{\sigma}\le\frac{\sigma+|t|}{\sigma}\le1+\frac{|t|}{\delta}\le c_\delta(4+|t|)$ for a constant $c_\delta$ - does this look correct?

Comment: Yes use the triangle inequality $|a+ib| \le |a|+|b|$

Comment: That's what the first inequality is; seems like I was just thinking slowly today. Thanks!

Comment: Also take a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021975/zeta-functions-asymptotic-zeta-sigmait-mathcalot1-sigma-epsilo/2022183#2022183