# How to show that $\sum_{d=1}^n 1/\sqrt{d} - 2 \sqrt{n}$ converges to a constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

We can approximate 
$$S_n = \sum_{d=1}^n 1/\sqrt{d}$$ 
by showing that
$$
S_n \le \int_0^n \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}} \mathrm dx = 2 \sqrt{n},
$$
and
$$
S_n \ge \int_1^{n+1} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}} \mathrm dx = 2 \sqrt{n} - O(1).
$$

My questions is, is it true that $S_n - 2\sqrt{n}$ converges to a constant?

If this is true, how can we prove it?

Comment: It's negative and increasing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may notice that
$$ 2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tag{1}$$
and the LHS of $(1)$ is a telescopic term. In particular:
$$ \left(2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}\right)^2}\tag{2}$$
and the RHS of $(2)$ is a non-negative and summable (by the p-test) term for $n\geq 1$.
As a consequence,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(-2\sqrt{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})^2}=C<0.\tag{3}$$
Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\zeta(s)$ for any $s:\text{Re}(s)>1$ and we are regularizing a divergent series, by analytic continuation we have
$$ C=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx -1.4603545088\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
I'll use the following identity ( from a previous [@Vorhang user post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030693/estimate-for-the-riemann-zeta-function) ):
$$
\sum_{1 \leq\ d\ \leq\ x}{1 \over d^{s}} = {x^{1 - s} \over 1 - s} + \zeta\pars{s} -
{\braces{x} \over x^{s}} + s\int_{x}^{\infty}{\braces{u} \over u^{s + 1}}
\,\dd u\,,\qquad
\Re\pars{s} > 0.
$$
$$
\mbox{It leads to}\quad\bbox[#ffd,15px]{
\sum_{d = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{d}} - 2\root{n} =
\zeta\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{u} \over u^{3/2}}\,\dd u}
$$
$$
\mbox{However,}\quad
0 < \verts{{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{u} \over u^{3/2}}\,\dd u} <
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\dd u \over u^{3/2}} = {1 \over \root{n}}
\implies
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{u} \over u^{3/2}}\,\dd u} = 0
$$

---

$$
\mbox{Then,}\quad
\bbx{\ds{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{d = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{d}} - 2\root{n}} =
\zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}} \approx -1.4604
$$

Comment: What is $\zeta(s)$ at the OP's level ?

Comment: @user1952009: $\zeta(s)$ is what $\zeta(s)$ is, that does not depend on the OP's "level". If the OP needs some clarification, he is free to ask. (+1) back.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't agree at all. And using $\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1}-s \int_1^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1}dx$ makes what Felix wrote almost trivial

Comment: @user1952009: you do not agree about what? About the OP being free to ask or about the Riemann $\zeta$ function being what it is?