# Riemann zeta function on the line Re(s) = 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, special-functions

How can I prove that for $s \in \mathbb{C}$, with real part of $s$ being equal to 1, 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}
\end{equation}
diverges?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It only diverges when $s = 1$. The Riemann zeta function has a meromorphic continuation to the entire complex plane with a single pole at $s = 1$. If the series diverged for all $s$ with $\textrm{Re}(s) = 1$, then such a continuation would not be possible.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Heh, the problem with ye olde Lacunary series.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise not at all

Comment: @EthanAlwaise an example : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n} = \frac{1}{1-z}$ but the series on the LHS diverges for every $|z| = 1$

Answer (score 6):

$$\left|n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx\right| = \left|\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx\right| <\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x  |s \, n^{-s-1}|dtdx = \left|\frac{s}{2}n^{-s-1}\right|$$

therefore

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^{-s}-\frac{1-N^{1-s}}{s-1}\right| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx\right| < \frac{|s|}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |n^{-s-1}|$$
and hence : $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ converges as $N \to \infty$ if and only if $\displaystyle\frac{1-N^{1-s}}{s-1}$ converges.

$$\boxed{\text{but for } Re(s) = 1, s \ne 1 : \quad \lim_{N \to \infty} N^{1-s} \quad \text{fails to exist}}$$

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: @DanielFischer and you might be interested that a direct generalization of this [gives $\zeta(\sigma+it) = \mathcal{O}(t^{1-\sigma+\epsilon})$ as $t \to \infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021975/zeta-functions-asymptotic-zeta-sigmait-mathcalot1-sigma-epsilo/2022183#2022183) in the critical strip

Answer (score 2):

Using formula $(10)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2027588),
$$
\zeta(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^s}-\frac1{1-s}n^{1-s}+\frac12n^{-s}\right]
$$
converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt-1$.

For $s=1+it$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^s}=\zeta(s)-\frac1{it}e^{-it\log(n)}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)
$$
Because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{-it\log(n)}$ does not exist for $t\ne0$, the series on the left does not converge. In fact, it orbits $\zeta(s)$ at a distance of approximately $\frac1{|1-s|}$.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the Riemann Zeta function diverges only for $s=1$. For $s\neq 1$, however, the function is convergent.As for divergence at $s=1$, there are many proofs extant, one of which is the [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). The function's definition in the form given by you is valid only for $Re(s)>1$.For other regions, we need to use other representations, one of which, as pointed by DonAntonio in the comments, in series form, for $Re(s)>0$ is  using [Dirichlet Eta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html).The convergence at $Re(s)=1,s\neq1$ can be proved by observing that $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ converges for $Re(s)>0,s\neq1$. The convergence for $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ at $Re(s)=1$ is proved using the theory of convergence of Dirichlet series to the right of the absscica of convergence, which, in this case, is $Re(s)>0$. It may also be seen by expanding $\zeta(s)$ around $s=1$ as a [Laurent Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) giving $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^n$, where $\gamma_n$ is the [Steiljes Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants). The Laurent series can be derived by using the integral representation of Riemann Zeta function and several methods can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/how-to-show-that-the-laurent-series-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-has-gamma-as).

---

The theorem on convergence of Dirichlet Series $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ is proved using boundedness of partial sums of $|(-1)^{n-1}|\leq1$ and the use of [Abel's summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) or [Euler's Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) on $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$. Alternatively, a proof of the same is given in Robjon's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/how-to-show-that-the-laurent-series-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-has-gamma-as) using Generalized Dirichlet's test for sum of product of two sequences.

Comment: Notice that your forms of the zeta function are not the original problem.  It is almost like saying it converges for $\Re(s)<0$ since your Laurent series converges for $\Re(s)<0$, though this is trivially false.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your first form for $\;\zeta(s)\;$ ? I can't see it...

Comment: @DonAntonio I took the expression from here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Dirichlet_series

Comment: @SimpleArt dosent the Riemann Zeta converge for $Re(s)<0$?

Comment: @vidyarthi which is not equal to the series above for $\Re(s)\le1$.

Comment: @SimpleArt So, shall I remove the Laurent series?

Comment: It is not that.  It is that your argument is wrong altogether.  You have not proven anything except the obvious divergence at $s=1$.  Everything else is secretly giberish.

Comment: @vidyarthi That's what I assumed, but you have a huge mistake there...and anyway it is easier, imo, to extend the convergence region to $\;\text{Re}\,z>0,\,\,z\neq1\;$ by means of the Dirichlet's Eta function.

Comment: Or just extend it to all $s\ne1$.  But that is not the question at hand, is it?

Comment: @SimpleArt The extension to $\;s\neq1\;$ requires way more than a simple extension to real part positive: the functional equation for the zeta function. What is enough here is for positive real part and that is way easier, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio Nah, the given Laurent series converges for all $s\ne1$, does it not?

Comment: @SimpleArt You mean the first given series in the answer above? It even isn't the correct one for the zeta function!

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

Comment: @SimpleArt Oh, the other one. Yes, yet the Stieljes constant is something that I don't like very much...and I also don't know it well. I'd rather go with the eta function.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well yes, I can't disagree with you on that one.

Comment: @DonAntonio:  As a side comment, just to make sure it's clear: one doesn't need the functional eq'n to get analytic continuation of the zeta function; repeated summation by parts (among other possibilities) gives a formulas that converge in any vertical right half-plane.  (This answer shows the first step of this, so as to convergence on Re $s >0$.)

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, edited the post.

Comment: @SimpleArt thanks, modified the post.

Comment: The convergence of the Dirichlet eta function has nothing to do here...

Comment: The question whether the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges or diverges when $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$ is a different question than whether the Riemann $\zeta$-function is analytic on a neighbourhood of $s$ when $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$ and $s\neq 1$.