# Riemann zeta function asymptotic on vertical lines $\sigma >1$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

In the proof of [Prop. 19 in these notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/12/17/254a-notes-10-mean-values-of-nonpretentious-multiplicative-functions/), Tao uses that for $|t|\leq 100$ and $\delta \ll |t|$ one has
$$|\zeta(1+\delta + it)| \asymp \frac{1}{|t|}.$$
(i.e. in the region $\mathscr R:= \{s=\sigma+it : |t|\leq 100, 1 <\sigma -1 \leq m|t|\}$ for some "slope" $m$ [visualized here on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a4min4dzvd), there are "implicit constants" $c,C>0$ s.t.
$$c |t|^{-1} \leq |\zeta(s)| \leq C |t|^{-1}.$$

I was able to prove this in a very "stupid" way. For $s\in B(1, \epsilon)$, the Laurent series expansion gives $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + O(1)$, so in $\mathscr R \cap B(1, \epsilon)$ we get the desired bounds. Then on the compact set $\overline{\mathscr R}\setminus B(1,\epsilon)$, we know that $\zeta$ is takes finite values (no poles), and is non-zero (in particular using the sledgehammer of nonvanishing of $\zeta$ on the line $\Re(s)=1$...), we get $|\zeta(s)| \asymp 1 \asymp |t|^{-1}$.

I am very displeased with this, because this proof really didn't say anything about the decay of the zeta function on vertical lines, which I think was the point of the asymptotic.

Here's my question:

> **Question**: is it true that on vertical lines right of the critical strip (i.e. $\Re(s)=\sigma >1$),
> $$|\zeta(s)| \asymp_{\sigma} \langle t\rangle ^{-1}?$$
> *Notation*: $\langle t\rangle:= (1+|t|^2)^{1/2}$ is the so-called Japanese bracket (which in particular is sim to $\asymp \min\{|t|^{-1}, 1\}$ if that is more intuitive notation), and the subscript means the implicit constant depends on $\sigma$.
>
> If not, what about on truncated vertical lines $\{\sigma + it: |t|\leq T\}$; and then how does the implicit constant depend on $T$? How do the implicit constants behave depending on $\sigma$? For example, restricting to a compact/bounded range of $\sigma$ and/or $T$, do we get uniform implicit constants?

**Remarks:** there are a number a questions on the asymptotic behavior of zeta on vertical lines in the critical strip, like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162625/leading-order-behaviour-of-riemann-zeta-function; the answers therein tell us that the [universality of the zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality) means that there can be no such asymptotics in the critical strip (note that the universality of the zeta function is limited to *inside* the critical strip). There are of course some upper bounds [Zeta function's asymptotic $\zeta(\sigma+it) = \mathcal{O}(|t|^{1-\sigma+\epsilon})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021975/zeta-functions-asymptotic-zeta-sigmait-mathcalot1-sigma-epsilo?rq=1).

Comment: Look up the universality of the Riemann Zeta function. I think this'll dispute your first claim on the Japanese Bracket asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: @SeanNemetz zeta function universality seems to only be relevant when talking about values inside the critical strip, at least from what I see on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: oh my apologies, I misread the $1+\delta+it$ for $\frac{1}{2}+\delta+it$.

Comment: See chapter $11$ of Titchmarsh RZ book for $\zeta$ on vertical lines; general Dirichlet series stuff implies that if $\sigma >1, \zeta(\sigma+it)$ takes or has as limits all allowable values $t \to \infty$ so, for example, there is $t_n \to \infty, \zeta(\sigma+it_n) \to \zeta(\sigma)$ which is, of course, the highest value possible in absolute value; similarly, we either can have $\zeta(\sigma+it_n) \to 0$ if $\sigma$ close enough to $1$ to allow it or $\zeta(\sigma+it_n) \to 2-\zeta(\sigma)$ if that is positive and then that is the lowest value allowable

Answer (score 1):

On a fixed vertical line $\Re s=\sigma$ with $\sigma>1$, the average value of $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ is asymptotically $1$ (by absolute convergence one can average each term of the Dirichlet series separately). So there's definitely no way $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ can decay as $|t|\to\infty$.

Indeed $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ will have a limiting distribution on such a line, which is the same as the limiting distribution of the random variable
$$
\prod_p (1-Z_p p^{-\sigma})^{-1},
$$
where the $Z_p$ are independent random variables (indexed by the primes) that are uniformly distributed on the unit circle in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also provide a reference? And by "limiting distribution on such a line", do you mean the limit of the measures: cut up $\mathbb C$ into tiny boxes, and find the normalized measure of points on the vertical line segment $\sigma + i[-T,T]$ that land in a given box? And finally is it possible to give some sort of description of what the random variable distribution will look like (like a picture, some sort of "heat map" $\subseteq \mathbb C$ for where the probability distribution is most concentrated)?